# Английский язык как язык специальности/специальностей?

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно написать : "Английский язык как язык специальности  (или "... язык специальностей") в средних профессиональных учебных заведений в контексте политики языкового образования"?

Answer (score -1):

Оба варианта имеют право на существование, какой именно выбрать — определяется из контекста: рассказываете вы о какой-то одной специальности или о нескольких.